# $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $N>0$ be an integer and  $A$ be a commutative free algebra of rank $2$ over $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$. Is it true that $A$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}[X])/(P)$ where $P \in (\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})[X]$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by free algebra? Free of rank 2 as a $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$-module?

Comment: Yep, that is right.

Comment: Then it is close to true, assuming $A$ has an identity. $P$ cannot be assumed to be irreducible, but $P$ can be assumed to be monic and quadratic. It describes what happens when you square the other basis element.

Comment: Well you have to assume that there exists a basis of the form $(a,1)$ no ? I mean if you have a basis $(a,b)$ you get $a^2 -ua -vb = 0$ (with $(u,v)\in \mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}^2$) and you need $b$ to be one to take $P = X^2 -uX -v \in (\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})[X])$).

Comment: Yes, but such a basis exists. It probably exists for easy reasons, but also because $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ is self-injective so the $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$-span of $1_A$ is an injective submodule, so a (module theoretic) direct summand of $A$. That part is true for any unital $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$-algebra (free or not, arbitrary rank).

Comment: I can't say I have understood that last comment, sorry. But thanks for trying.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85600/finite-abelian-groups-direct-sum-of-cyclic-subgroup for an elementary proof

Comment: Ok I think I undertsand thanks.